# Is there a way to delay the C++/SEH exception

Tags: c++

Is there a way to delay a crash i.e. sleep for a few seconds to have logs recorded in the background and then continue the original exception (It's a multi-threaded application)? I want to check the type of C++ exception/SEH exception and then handle it or let it crash (not recover it).

I thought of using exit(1) but it is not preferable to terminate the program after sleep, as destructors might not be registered with the operating system may not be executed leading to resource leaks. It will also make it difficult to diagnose the crash.

Comment: So, are you able to catch the exception?

Comment: Yes, via _set_se_translator or try-catch, however, that will just catch it.

Comment: What do you need more than `catch`? You can re`throw` the exception or reinitiate the algorithm with modified inputs. What else do you plan to do?!

Comment: IMO a crash is a crash (specially SEH, access violation your code is in an undefined state), even if you handle it there is no guarantee you can log everyhting. On crash you should be able to let OS write a crashdump which you can analyze in your debugger later, this will really help you pinpoint source of the exception.

Comment: Windows will release all resources of process when it is terminated, regardless if destructors ran or not. For terminating insane processes I would prefer abort(). That will generate post-mortem debugging files if everything has been set up correctly.

Comment: @Red.Wave is there a way to re-throw SEH exception?

Comment: @batmon ***Yes, via _set_se_translator or try-catch, however, that will just catch it***. Anything between a `throw` and the `catch` block is unwided. With proper cuation, anything between the `__try` and `throw` is also unwinded. Now mark the dumping function as `noexcept` to skip every upperhand catch block. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-se-translator?view=msvc-170